# duda con los props en vue y los componentes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3

tengo una tabla de elementos la cual lleno mediante la directiva v-for en esta misma tabla tambien llamo 2 botones componentes a los cuales les paso la id del elemento para poder borrar y editar en base al id el problema que me surge es que mi componente boton cuando se clickea llama a un modal y luego ese modal al confirmar elimina el elemento.

pues tengo una funcion llamada deleteItem la cual solamente escribe el id del elemento por consola cuando clikeo el 1 elemento me escribe el id tanto en el boton como en el boton del modal

pero en el segundo elemento me escribe el id correcto del siguiente elemento pero cuando le doy al boton del modal aparece es el id del 1 elemento y asi con los siguientes en el boton que activa el modal aparece el id correcto pero luego en el boton del modal que llama la misma funcion siempre llama al 1 id adjunto codigo y capturas de consola

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid table-container shadow-sm p-5" v-if="accounts">
    <!-- title + icon -->
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-wallet fs-2 me-3 text-primary"></i>
      <span class="fs-4">
        Metodos de Pago
      </span>  
      <button class="ms-auto d-flex align-items-center btn btn-outline-primary p-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addAcountModal">
        Agregar
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fs-2 ms-2"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
      <!-- data table with accounts -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">Alias</th>
            <th scope="col">Entidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Documento de Identidad</th>
            <th scope="col">Numero de cuenta</th>
            <th scope="col">tipo de cuenta</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="text-center" v-for="account in accounts" :key="account.id">
            <td>{{account.alias}}</td>
            <td>{{account.entity}}</td>
            <td>{{account.document}}</td>
            <td>{{account.acountNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{account.type}}</td>
            <td class="d-flex" v-if="account">
              <EditButton class="me-2" :account="account"/>
              <DeleteButton :id="account.id"/> 
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- modal for add account -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="addAcountModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addaccountlabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-sm-down">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registrar cuenta nueva</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="text-start">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Alias:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="acct.alias">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Entidad:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="acct.entity">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Documento de Identidad:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="acct.document">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Numero de cuenta:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" v-model="acct.acountNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Tipo de cuenta:</label>
              <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" v-model="acct.type">
                <option value="ahorro">Ahorro</option>
                <option value="corriente">Corriente</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @click="saveNewAcct">Guardar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import { randomId } from '@/helpers/randomNum';


export default{
  name: 'DataTable',
  data(){
    return{
      acct:{
      "id":'',
      "alias":'',
      "entity":'',
      "document":'',
      "acountNumber":'',
      "type":'',
      }
    }
  },
  components:{
    DeleteButton: defineAsyncComponent( () => import('./DeleteButon.vue')),
    EditButton: defineAsyncComponent( () => import('./EditButton.vue')),
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapState('accountModule',['accounts'])
  },
  methods:{
    ...mapActions('accountModule',['createAccount']),
    saveNewAcct(){
      let newAcct = {
      "id": randomId(),
      "alias":this.acct.alias,
      "entity":this.acct.entity,
      "document":this.acct.document,
      "acountNumber":this.acct.acountNumber,
      "type":this.acct.type,
      }
      this.createAccount(newAcct);
      this.acct.id = '';
      this.acct.alias = '';
      this.acct.entity = '';
      this.acct.document = '';
      this.acct.acountNumber = '';
      this.acct.type = '';
      console.log(this.acct);
      console.log(newAcct);
      
    },
  },
}
</script>

<Style lang="scss" scoped>
.table-container{
  height: calc(100% - 25% - 1.5rem);
}
.fa-plus,
.btn-outline-primary{
  &:hover{
    color:#ffffff !important;
  }
  &:focus{
    color:#ffffff !important;
  }
}
</Style>
```

y este es el componente boton

```html
<template>
  <div>
<button @click="deleteItem" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-sm-down">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModal">Eliminar Elemento</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      quieres borrar?
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @click="deleteItem">Guardar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'DeleteButton',
  props:{
    id:{
      type:String,
    },
  },
  methods:{
    ...mapActions('accountModule',['deleteAccount']),
    deleteItem(){
      // this.deleteAccount(this.item);
      console.log(this.id);
    },
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden cuando le doy a guardar se escribe el id del primer elemento  ??? pero cuando le di originalmente al boton se escribe el id correcto a que se debe esto ? si todo esta en el mismo componente

Comment: Al parecer el problema se debe a que siempre estas mostrando el modal `id="addAcountModal"` y si hay más de uno (_como sería el caso_) siempre encuentrar el primero. Te recomiendo no usar `id` para buscar el modal. Otra sería usar [`uuid`](https://github.com/VitorLuizC/vue-uuid)

Comment: y de que manera podria actualizar por decirlo asi el id en el mismo modal ?

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el método `deleteItem` que es muestra el modal?

Comment: El método solo es un consolé logncon el ID

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Remover los atributos `data` del botón y también el atributo `id` del `.modal`

```html
<button @click="deleteItem" class="btn btn-danger">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
</button>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
```

- Modificar el método `deleteItem` para mostrar el modal. Para buscarlo podes utilizar [`this.$el`](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el)

```js
deleteItem(){
  let elModal = this.$el.querySelector('.modal'),
    bsModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(elModal);

  bsModal.show();
}
```